# C# how to dynamically cast an object?

Tags: c#

I am building a helper object that has a property called Mailer. In reality Mailer can be either a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage or a Mono.System.Net.Mail.MailMessage. So I would preferably only want 1 declaration of mailer.

For example I don't want:

```
private Mono.Mailing.MailMessage MonoMessage = new Mono.Mailing.MailMessage();
private System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
```

I would prefer

```
object mailer;
```

Then in constructor

```
switch (software)
            {
                case EnunInternalMailingSoftware.dotnet:
                    this.mailer = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    break;
                case EnunInternalMailingSoftware.mono:
                    this.mailer = new Mono.Mailing.MailMessage(); 
                    break;
            }
```

The problem is that mailer has no properties at design time. So I can't compile my code.

How can this be fixed, am I taking the right approach. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the adapter pattern for this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Define an interface that covers the methods you need (e.g. SendMail()) and then write a simple adapter class for each MailMessage object that implements the interface and delegates to the correct methods on the specific MailMessage class.

Comment: can you please provide some basic outlines?

Comment: @JL - Define an IMailer interface that contains the methods you would want to call.  Then you create an MonoMailerAdapter class that implements this interface and holds an instance of the Mono Mailer class which it can delegate method calls to.  Similarly create an adapter for the System.Net version.  Then your `object mailer;` field becomes `IMailer mailer;`

Comment: I think I get it - the mailer is defined as an interface (IMailer) - then you cast to the adapter class (which implements IMailer) in the constructor of the calling class?

Comment: @JL - close, there shouldn't be any need to cast the interface to one of the adapters.  You should just use the IMailer interface everywhere so your code doesn't care whether it's being passed the System.Net version or the Mono version.  e.g. `public void Dostuff(IMailer mailer) { mailer.SendMail("Get this sent!"); }`