# How can I cast object dynamically?

Tags: c#, casting

I am pretty sure this was asked before but unfortunately the only thing I've found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903450/c-sharp-how-to-dynamically-cast-an-object) that was not solution for me. In my current project I do something like:

```
private object obj;

private void Initialize()
{
    obj.Initialize();
}

private void CreateInstanceA()
{
    obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClassA));
}

private void CreateInstanceB()
{
    obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClassB));
}
```

This code does not work of course because I've not cast `obj` because its type changes dynamically.

How can I cast it dynamically?

Comment: It seems like this would not be the best way to go about things. Kind of a code smell to me. What is the larger context of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Aside from initializing it, what else do you intend to do with `obj`?

Comment: @RaymondChen I've just made simple WinForm project to test my class libraries.

Comment: @PLB I'm afraid my question was not sufficienty clear. Let me try again. "How do the other methods in your class (the ones other than `Initialize`, `CreateInstanceA` and `CreateInstanceB`) use the `obj` member?" Whatever technique those other methods use, you can use in your `Initialize` method.

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh, it's clear now. `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` have the same interface.

Comment: @PLB Then use that interface to initialize the object. In fact, you should declare `obj` as `private ICommonInterface obj` so that it's clear that `obj` will always implement that common interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three options:

- If you control both classes, and you can make them implement a common interface that includes everything you need, then do that - and cast to the interface
- If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4, you can use dynamic typing - just declare the variable as `private dynamic obj;` and it will compile and find the right method at execution time
- Otherwise, use reflection to find and call the method.

Basically *casting* based on an execution time type doesn't make sense, as part of the point of casting is to give the *compiler* more information... and you simply don't have that in this case.

The first option is by far the nicest if you can possibly achieve it.

Comment: what about Dependency Injection

Comment: Dependency Injection without Interfaces/Abstract base class? How? If interfaces can be defined, scenario first is sufficient

Comment: Wouldn't a base class be better, as opposed to an interface? This is an *is-a* (abstract class), as opposed to a *can-do* (interface). Assuming the types are similar in nature of course

Comment: @mattytommo What makes you say that?  We just know that we are creating two different classes that need to be initialized.  They may not be related at all.

Comment: @Servy Note that I said *Assuming the types are similar in nature of course* :)

Comment: @mattytommo And what's your basis for that assumption?

Comment: @Servy I don't have one, but I wondered why just an interface is recommended, surely that assumption there was the types are **not** related, what's the basis for that assumption? :) I was just trying to cover both grounds really.

Comment: @mattytommo I can think of a lot of different things that might need to be initialized.  In fact, most any object I can think of could implement an "initializeable" interface if there was a compelling reason to defer initialization until after the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that CreatInstanceB() should actually use MyClassB, correct?

In which case you can use:

```
((MyClassA)obj).Initialize();
```

...

```
((MyClassB)obj).Initialize();
```

Or you could make an interface which has an Initialize method and define obj as that interface.

Comment: i think, in the initialize method, MyClassA, or MyClassB are not known, which is the point in the question

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've edited question. I'd better use `dynamic` keyword as @JonSkeet suggested.

Comment: True, missed that.  We can always rely on Mr Skeet.